# Doctrine retrieve and order data at 1 and 2 tables depth

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have 3 tables in doctrine, for simplicity's sake I'll call them: `U`, `M` and `R`

`U` can have `M`'s and `R`'s

`M` can have `R`'s

`R` can have nothing

As a diagram this might look like:

```
U ---> M
|      |
|      V
'----> R
```

what I want to do is create one query to get all `R`'s related to `U` either through `M` or directly ordered by a column in `R` and queried by a column in `R`.

in PHP currently I have:

```
$qb->select('r')
    ->from('R','r')
    ->where('r.u = :uid')
    ->orderBy('r.order','DESC')
    ->setParameter('uid', $U->getId())
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit )
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like('r.q1',':query'),
            $qb->expr()->like('r.q2',':query')
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('query', "%" . $query . "%");
```

I want to join `m.r`'s somehow while still being able to query their properties. I have tried:

```
$qb->select('u.r, m.r')
    ->from('U','u')
    ->where('u.id = :uid')
    ->join('u.m','m')
    ->orderBy('u.r.order','DESC')
    ->setParameter('uid', $U->getId())
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit )
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like('u.r.q1',':query'),
            $qb->expr()->like('u.r.q2',':query')
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('query', "%" . $query . "%");
```

As well as many other things but to no avail...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I ended up doing was:

Select all the ID's from `M` where `u.id = :uid`

then, select all from `R` where `r.u = :uid OR r.m IN (result from first query)`

Simple really, I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier...